# Try to change the logger level at the root level

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

when i try to change logger dynamically through actuator at the root level. By this curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "TRACE"}' http://localhost:8080/loggers/ROOT through postman . I am getting this `2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1]` then i am getting this message in springboot.

```
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: (port 56554) op = 82
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: (port 56554) op = 80
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.misc                   : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: getting input stream
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.misc                   : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: call dispatcher
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.server.call                      : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl[3608b57d:18e096ca6f3:-7ffc, 4112126016260015251]: public abstract java.lang.String javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnection.getDefaultDomain(javax.security.auth.Subject) throws java.io.IOException]
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 TRACE 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.remote.rmi              : connectionId=rmi://127.0.0.1  1
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.remote.misc             : Receive a new request.
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.remote.misc             : Finish a request.
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.remote.timeout          : Admin: Timestamp=1709555267927
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.misc                   : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: getting output stream
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [tion timeout 17] javax.management.remote.timeout          : Admin: elapsed=0
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [tion timeout 17] javax.management.remote.timeout          : Admin: remaining timeout=120000
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [tion timeout 17] javax.management.remote.misc             : Waiting with timeout: 120000 ms remaining
2024-03-04 17:57:48.241 DEBUG 15432 --- [80-ClientPoller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1709555268241; nextExpiration=1709555268235; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
```

please suggest me how to disable this mssg.

i try to change the logger level at the root level that has been changed but getting this mssg how diable this mssg.

```
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: (port 56554) op = 82
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: (port 56554) op = 80
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.misc                   : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: getting input stream
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.misc                   : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: call dispatcher
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.server.call                      : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl[3608b57d:18e096ca6f3:-7ffc, 4112126016260015251]: public abstract java.lang.String javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnection.getDefaultDomain(javax.security.auth.Subject) throws java.io.IOException]
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 TRACE 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.remote.rmi              : connectionId=rmi://127.0.0.1  1
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.remote.misc             : Receive a new request.
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.remote.misc             : Finish a request.
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.remote.timeout          : Admin: Timestamp=1709555267927
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] sun.rmi.transport.misc                   : RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: getting output stream
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [tion timeout 17] javax.management.remote.timeout          : Admin: elapsed=0
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [tion timeout 17] javax.management.remote.timeout          : Admin: remaining timeout=120000
2024-03-04 17:57:47.927 DEBUG 15432 --- [tion timeout 17] javax.management.remote.misc             : Waiting with timeout: 120000 ms remaining
2024-03-04 17:57:48.241 DEBUG 15432 --- [80-ClientPoller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1709555268241; nextExpiration=1709555268235; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
```

Comment: You enabled trace logging for evereything and now you wondering why you are seeing debug and trace messages?

Answer (score 0):

just create a file named logging.properties in your spring boot application's classpath with this line:

```
sun.rmi.transport.tcp=INFO
```

It will supress the debug messages.

Those messages come from the sun.rmi.transport.tcp package, which by default, is configured with a debug level.

Comment: it is possible to suppress the all the log mssg from this .whether it is  (info debug .... etc)